# Keep a jQuery dialog in a div

Tags: jquery-ui, jdialog, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to create a number of jQuery dialogs but I would like to constrain their positions to inside a parent div. I am using the following code to create them (on a side note the oppacity option is not working either...):

```
var d= $('<div title="Title goes here"></div>').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: dx,
            height: dy
        });

        d.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
        d.draggable('option', 'opacity', 0.45);

        $('#controlContent').append(d.parent());
```

Comment: is #controlContent having position: relative/absolute?

Comment: I have not specified either, I have just tried setting it to relative and nothing has changed and setting it to absolute makes the content pane of the dialog disappear and just keeps the title bar of the jDialog...

Comment: Cause setting a parent to position: relative makes the childrens top/left relative to its parent, not the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it. This is now my method for creating a dialog:

```
    var d = $('<div title="Title"></div>').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });

    d.parent().find('a').find('span').attr('class', 'ui-icon ui-icon-minus');
    d.parent().draggable({
        containment: '#controlContent',
        opacity: 0.70
    });

    $('#controlContent').append(d.parent());
```

Answer (score 9):

A bit more helpful and complete version of above solution.

It even limits the resizing outside of the div too!

And the JavaScript is fully commented.

```
// Public Domain
// Feel free to use any of the JavaScript, HTML, and CSS for any commercial or private projects. No attribution required.
// I'm not responsible if you blow anything up with this code (or anything else you could possibly do with this code).

jQuery(function($) 
{ 
    // When the document is ready run the code inside the brackets.
    $("button").button(); // Makes the button fancy (ie. jquery-ui styled)
    $("#dialog").dialog(
    { 
        // Set the settings for the jquery-ui dialog here.
        autoOpen: false, // Don't open the dialog instantly. Let an event such as a button press open it. Optional.
        position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: "#constrained_div" } // Set the position to center of the div.
    }).parent().resizable(
    { 
        // Settings that will execute when resized.
        containment: "#constrained_div" // Constrains the resizing to the div.
    }).draggable(
    { 
        // Settings that execute when the dialog is dragged. If parent isn't used the text content will have dragging enabled.
        containment: "#constrained_div", // The element the dialog is constrained to.
        opacity: 0.70 // Fancy opacity. Optional.
    });

    $("#button").click(function() 
    { 
        // When our fancy button is pressed the stuff inside the brackets will be executed.
        $("#dialog").dialog("open"); // Opens the dialog.
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emilhem/rymEh/33/

Comment: Been looking for something like this for a few days now! Thanks!