# How do I attach a JQuery UI dialog to a specific DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there an easy way to stick jQuery UI dialog to particular div?

Actually, one should be able to drag or resize dialog but dialog should not leave the div.

```
<script>
var dialogOptions = {
    title: "Recent",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    width:200,
    position: {
        my: "left top", at:"left+10 top+10", of:".frame"
    },
    "modal" : false,
    "resizable" : true,
    "draggable" : true,
    appendTo: ".frame"
};

$( "div.dialog" ).dialog(dialogOptions);
</script>

<div class="frame">
    <div class="dialog">
    </div>
</div>
```

Pls check http://jsfiddle.net/TLt4b/1/

Comment: This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13020172/1696560

Comment: You need to constrain the movement of the dialog. http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var dialogOptions = {
title: "Recent",
closeOnEscape: false,
width:200,
position: {
    my: "left top", at:"left+10 top+10", of:".frame"
},
"modal" : false,
"resizable" : true,
"draggable" : true,
appendTo: ".frame"  };


$( "div.dialog" ).dialog(dialogOptions).parent().resizable({
    containment: ".frame" 
}).draggable({ 
        containment: ".frame"       
})
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/TLt4b/2/

Comment: Thanks Mohit, this works partly.Try resizing to bottom right, so you will notice certain padding of red box deny to resize dialog all over the red container.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/TLt4b/4/

**JS:-**

```
var dialogOptions = {
    title: "Recent",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    width:200,
    position: {
        my: "left top", at:"left+10 top+10", of:".frame"
    },
    modal : false,
    resizable : true
};

$( "div.dialog" ).dialog(dialogOptions).parent().draggable({ containment: ".frame" });
```