# jQuery UI - Prevent dialog from dragging above div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there a way to prevent jQuery UI dialog from going above or below `#top` div? I'm not looking for z-index solution, but rather something like offset from the top. In this case dialog should be unable to be moved to area where is `#top` div.

Any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="dialog">My dialog</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen:true,
                            modal: false,
                            resizable: true,
                            draggable: true,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            title: "Title",
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/9gku6qrh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for - [Keep a jQuery dialog in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315262/keep-a-jquery-dialog-in-a-div) - you would just need put a parent container around `#dialog`.

Comment: You are correct. New jsfiddle with solution https://jsfiddle.net/10h8qjov/